# build print div button in angular using slectedData undefined

Tags: angular

I build a basic form for print JSON data in the input, i get the right data from JSON (i put a console log in the method for see get the correct data), i get two diferent method for build this, the second is using ngx-print but don't work, this don't show data in the inputs

but send me error undefined when i try print data from form, i have this...

component .ts

```js
 selectedExamen;
  constructor(private dataService: dataService, public dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.getExamenes();
    this.selectedExamen = {
      id: -1, nombreExa: '', descripcionExa: '',
      release_date: '', fechaExa: '', categoriaExa: '', nombrePac: '',
      apellidoPac: '', rutPac: '', apellidoDoc: '', nombreDoc: ''
    };

  }
examenClicked = (exa) => {

    this.dataService.getOneExamen(exa.id).subscribe(
      (data: Examen) => {
        console.log(this.selectedExamen);
        this.selectedExamen = data;

      },
      error => {
        alert('Error al Conectar Datos ');
      }
    );
  }
  print = (exa) => {
    this.dataService.getOneExamen(exa.id).subscribe(
      (data: Examen) => {
        console.log(this.selectedExamen);
        this.selectedExamen = data;

        let printContents, popupWin;
        printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
        popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>LABORATORIO CLINICO </title>
           </head>
       <H1>Reporte De Examen: </H1>
      <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${this.selectedExamen.nombreExa}</body>
      </html>`
        );
        popupWin.document.close();


      },
      error => {
        alert('Error al Conectar Datos ');
      }
    );
}
```

component .html

```html
  <div id="print-section"  class="modal-body">
   Nombre Paciente:<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectedExamen.nombrePac" readonly>

    <input hidden class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectedExamen.id" readonly>
  Fecha De Creación: <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectedExamen.release_date" readonly>   

</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="print(examenes)">Imprimir</button> 
      <button class="btn btn-primary" printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint >print</button>
```

service.ts

```js
getExamenes(): Promise<Examen[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseurl + '/examen?format=json', { headers: this.headers })
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json() as Examen[])
}

getOneExamen(id): Observable<Examen> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Examen>(this.baseurl + '/examen/' + id ,
    ).pipe()
}
```

[get the correct data from JSON / i need print data from this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQLVY.png)

Comment: Can you share more details about your "error"? Also, a Stackblitz would be nice!

Comment: Looks like the `id` property to your `getOneExamen` is coming through as `undefined`. In your `print` method you are using it passing `exa.id`. This means that the `id` property does not exist on the `exa` variable passed into the method. Your usage of the `print` method in your template make use of the `examenes` variable that I don't see in your code so I'm not sure what that is. You'll want to start verifying what that is.

Comment: i fix the error moving the button to the list